# How to reliably get county from Google Autocomplete/Details

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

If I use [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) for "Alpha Loft Elm" I get an address that includes only level 1 (state) in the administrative areas.  But if I autocomplete for the same place using the returned formatted_address, "844 Elm St, Manchester, NH 03101, United States", I get level 2 (county) as well, with a different place-id.

I see the same behavior for other places as well.  I see the same behavior from the [Place Details API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), when I give it the place-id returned in each case.

I need the county, and need to support autocomplete by place name.

The only workaround I've found for this is to use [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) (textsearch) on the returned formatted_address, then use Place Details on the placeId returned for the address to get the county.

Is there a better approach?

(Also posted as [a bug report on gmaps-api-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8663).)

Answer (score 0):

So far I am not aware of any other solution then after using Autocomplete to get the accurate address and place_id to use something like the following code to retrieve the "political" structure behind that address.

```
if (place.place_id) {
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.getDetails({placeId: place.place_id}, function (PlaceResult, PlacesServiceStatus) {
        console.log(PlaceResult);
    });
}
```